# Universal Windows Phone BottomAppBar disappears on resume

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

When running my app in the emulator or a phone the app bar only shows the first time the app is run. If I close the app and come back, the app bar is gone. Reinstalling or resetting the phone brings it back for one run. The app bar works fine in windows. I don't have any suspend/resume event code implemented yet. Below is a sample of the app bar code.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="SettingsButton" Icon="Setting" Label="Settings" />
            <AppBarButton x:Name="Help" Icon="Help" Label="Help" />
            <AppBarButton x:Name="Forms" Icon="Bullets" Label="Forms" IsEnabled="False" />
            <AppBarButton x:Name="ManageTrip" Icon="Manage" Label="Manage Trip" />
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="Sync" Icon="Sync" Label="Sync" />
        <AppBarButton x:Name="FilterSettings" Icon="Filter" Label="Filter" />
        <AppBarButton x:Name="AddTransaction" Icon="Add" Label="Add" />
        <AppBarButton x:Name="EditTransaction" Icon="OpenFile" Label="Open" />
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the AppBar would not load was that I was navigating to another page inside the OnViewLoaded event if I was already logged in. If I remove this redirection, the AppBar loads every time.

Comment: Good, remember to check your as best answer